# Ubuntu OS install in Android Mobile device using ubuntu-device-flash

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-for-android

For past few days I have been looking for a way to install Ubuntu Touch on my Moto-G(XT1033). So I tried some process and it failed with `failed to enter recovery`.

```
root@ram:/home/ram/Downloads# ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap --device=mako
    2015/11/02 23:24:46 Device is |mako|
    2015/11/02 23:24:46 Flashing version 24 from ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako

    Failed to enter Recovery

    +++++
```

Could anyone please help me on this issue. And if there is any process that was working for the installation of Ubuntu OS in mobile, please comment out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Touch is currently not available for the Moto G using the `ubntu-device-flash` method, as it isn't officially supported by Ubuntu yet. I recommend taking a look at [the currently supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) to see what might be available.

If you really want to install Ubuntu Touch, there is an experimental version [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/development/ubuntu-touch-utopic-ubuntu-touch-falcon-t2820359), but I recommend against using it, as the installation procedure is complicated and it might not even work once installed. Most of the features will probably be buggy, ruining the experience. If the installation goes wrong, which is highly likely, you could end up with a bricked device.

If you really want Ubuntu Touch, do it. Otherwise, **stay away**.

Comment: Hi Zacharee, I tried following the this link as well (http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/development/ubuntu-touch-utopic-ubuntu-touch-falcon-t2820359). But boot.img file is unable to download.. Anyways thanks for your comment.

Comment: Zacharee, If there is any other way to install Ubuntu Os in Moto-G apart from the above link, please do comment here ..

Comment: @RamMurthy that's the only way I know of. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

`--device=mako`. `mako` is the Nexus 4. You are trying to flash an N4 image to a Moto G. That isn't going to work. There is no official Ubuntu Touch support for the Moto G, but a developer did create an unofficial port on [XDA developers.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/development/ubuntu-touch-utopic-ubuntu-touch-falcon-t2820359) I'm not sure if it supports the XT1033 or not, but check it out.

Comment: Hi seth, Yes i know that mako is not for Moto-G, Having a trail to check if i can see Ubuntu flashed onto my Moto-G(falcon device type). Thanks for the comment.